# Trigger angular function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have following controller with the function which should be triggerd after click on the link:

```
<a id="1" href="" name="xxx" ng-click="searchall(id)">sample link</a>

ng.controller('SearchResultController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'Service', function ($scope, $stateParams, Service) {
    $scope.searchall = function () {
        $scope.SearchResult = Service.result;

        Service.searchall({ id: $stateParams.id }, function (data) {
            alert('SearchResultController');
            $scope.SearchResult = data;
        });        
    };
}]);
```

When I comment this:

```
Service.searchall({ id: $stateParams.id }, function (data) {             
    $scope.SearchResult = data;
});
```

The alert is shown in the browser thus I my controller is linked with the view but still I need the function to be call on the service. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you see any errors in console? if you not see alert, so request fail, or it still running

Comment: just wondering, is there a reason why you pass `id` in the a tag `searchall` call? It doesn't seem to be represented in the function code

Comment: I see 404 in the console after clicking on the link with the funcktion

Comment: So, the function is executed. It's just trying to access an incorrect link.

Comment: Also I agree with @OliverRadini , your function isn't accepting a parameter

Comment: when I hardcode the right id in the link like this: <a id="1" href="" name="xxx" ng-click="searchall(id='B997A8927574')">sample link</a>

Answer (score 0):

You should check value `$stateParams.id`. If this incorrect and you see in console 404 error, so you success handler not raised. If you add error handler, you can see that pipe work ok

```
Service.searchall({ id: $stateParams.id }, function (data) {
    alert('SearchResultController');
    $scope.SearchResult = data;
},function(){ //error handler
    alert('Something wrong');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without some more details, it's difficult to provide a conclusive answer, so here is an example of some variables being passed to a function in Angular: https://jsfiddle.net/jk0peh4h/1/

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">First Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="firstName">
    <br>Last Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="lastName">
    <button ng-click="testFunction(firstName, lastName)">Test</button>
</div>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.testFunction = function(firstName, lastName) {
                alert(firstName + " " + lastName);
            };
        });
    </script>
```

Difficult to know if that helps or not, but you may want to consult the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick